# Shrink WPF ListView row height to zero when it only contains collapsed items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, row, height

I have the following issue:
For my App I have a ListView with two columns. All the cells are filled with TextBlocks containing the data I want to display.
When I collapse both TextBlocks in a row they themselves occupy no space, BUT the "empty" row of the ListView still occupies a little space because it contains the collapsed TextBlocks.

Is there a way to tell the ListView to shrink the size of a row that only contains collapsed TextBlocks to zero? How and where could I make this modification?

I want the rows that still display some content to move together as if there where no (empty) lines in between them.

I made some pictures to show the state before and after collapsing some rows.

I hope this is not too silly of a question to ask but I couldn't find a solution or didn't know how to properly google this issue.

[All TextBlocks visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej7WP.png)

[Some TextBlocks collapsed but empty rows occupy space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBEcG.png)

EDIT:
My XAML code

```
<ListView FontFamily="Consolas" Margin="3,19,3,0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyEntryList}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <!-- This solved my problem -->
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <!-- This solved my problem -->
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Timestamp">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Timestamp}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Sessions">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Expander>
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <TextBlock Padding="{Binding Path=Indent, Converter={StaticResource IntToThicknessConverter}}" Text="{Binding Path=Ev}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <TextBlock Padding="{Binding Path=Indent, Converter={StaticResource IntToThicknessConverter}}" Text="{Binding Path=EvDetails}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </Expander>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Can you post your xaml please?

Comment: You may set the ListViewItem's Visibility to Collepsad in an ItemContainerStyle of the ListView.

Comment: @the.Doc Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: @Clemens Don't know if you associated my question to the similar question but this is exactly what I needed! Damn, so easy in the end.

Comment: I added the code that solved my problem to my XAML and marked it for everyone who is looking for a solution.